# iOS - NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER expected : (colon) in xcode 5

Tags: xcode, tapku

how can i use NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER in xcode 5 
it give me error  `Expected ':'`
i recognize the problem in xCode version  , it work fine with xCode 6

i find this code in TapkuLibrary
thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is the attribute

```
__attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
```

so define it in your pch

```
#ifndef NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
#else
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#endif
#endif
```

then you can also use it in xcode5